# Program to recognize music notation

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, ocr, image-recognition

I wrote program to recognize music notation (exactly tabulature). In the main there are digits on the lines.
After preprocessing (global binarization) I remove lines. 
I'd like to ask about preprocessing. My program works fine where lines and digits have the same color. But lines are often lighter than digits. When I use binarization with small threshold lines disapear when I use binarization with bigger threshold there are too many noises and digits are thick.

What kind of binarization (in OpenCV) can you recommend? What to do? Is there any solution for this problem?

I'll add some example.

My preprocessing looks like that:

1) Reading image in gray colors:

[image]

2) GLobal binarization:

cv::threshold (for example 127)

[image]

Characters are not beautiful... :( But main problem is that lines disappeared.

3) cv::threshold (230)

I can see lines but charackters are thick and ugly. For example 'a' character sometimes does not have empty space in the middle and so on. And there are a lot of noises. :(

[image]

And there is one more problem... I have to set threshold value for every file....

Do you have any suggestion for preprocesssing???

I'd like to have "nice" lines and characters...

(I don't ask about code, just some suggestions and advices.

Comment: Could you add some example images and more details?

Comment: Thanks. I'll send explanation with pictures.

Comment: @peter55555 Don't post it as an answer, edit your question. Answers are answers, this is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try out adaptive thresholding - taken from the OpenCV website:

> In the previous section, we used a global value as threshold value.
>   But it may not be good in all the conditions where image has different
>   lighting conditions in different areas. In that case, we go for
>   adaptive thresholding. In this, the algorithm calculate the threshold
>   for a small regions of the image. So we get different thresholds for
>   different regions of the same image and it gives us better results for
>   images with varying illumination.
>
> It has three ‘special’ input params and only one output argument.
>
> Adaptive Method - It decides how thresholding value is calculated.
>   cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C : threshold value is the mean of
>   neighbourhood area. cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C : threshold value
>   is the weighted sum of neighbourhood values where weights are a
>   gaussian window. Block Size - It decides the size of neighbourhood
>   area.
>
> C - It is just a constant which is subtracted from the mean or
>   weighted mean calculated.
>
> Below piece of code compares global thresholding and adaptive
>   thresholding for an image with varying illumination:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('dave.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

titles = ['Original Image', 'Global Thresholding (v = 127)',
            'Adaptive Mean Thresholding', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding']
images = [img, th1, th2, th3]

for i in xrange(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html

This provides more advanced thresholding which has a different threshold for different regions